# Dropdown list depending on two other dropdown lists

Tags: excel, list

I have several parameters:

```
- Company
- Position
- Person
- other information
```

I have a limited number of choices. I thought about creating dropdown lists with the third depending on the first two.

When I choose a company and a position, I would like to have only the person that works in this company at this position in my dropdown list - so two dependencies.

For example,
I choose 
Company: Siemens
Position: Secretary
I want to have the choise among all the secretary of Siemens. Not the other people working for Siemens and also not the secretary of an other company.

Comment: Could you post some detail about your inputs and desired outputs because it's unclear what you're asking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Dependent Dropdown Lists in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996838/multiple-dependent-dropdown-lists-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

(I hope you use a DB for this)
First you have to use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

this is always executed when your Excel Worksheet changed.
afterwards, you have to extract the values of the two Dropboxes.

With this two values you can get possible values for your third dropdown from the DB. This list, array or whatever can you add to your third dropdown.

This is just a little concept, but i have not enough information to give you exact answers.